# Log file creates too many entries but I don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, logging

I wrote a program that should write data into a separate file everytime I run the program. This works the first time, but as soon as I run the program again, it makes 2 entries, the third time it makes 4 entries, and so on. And I simply can't find the mistake.

This is the part of the code that should make the entry in the new file:

```
import datetime            
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='loghistory.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('loghistory.log')
ch = logging.FileHandler('loghistory.log',mode='w')
# to empty exisiting file:  logging.FileHandler('loghistory.log', mode ='w')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if q2==0 and q1==0:
    logger.debug('No airplanes within 5 km')
else:
    if q2 ==0 and q1>0:
       logger.debug('At least 1 airplane within 5 km') 
    else:
        if q2>0:
            logger.debug('At least 1 airplane within 2 km')
```

This is what it currently looks like:

```
03/07/2017 09:06:21 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 09:06:21 AM - DEBUG:loghistory.log:At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 09:06:21 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
```

but it should look like this:

```
03/07/2017 09:06:21 AM - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 09:06:22 AM - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 09:06:23 AM - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
```

one single new entry every second (or 2 seconds).

Here is the entire code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import winsound
from Tkinter import *


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# import and reduce data and change it to distances

data = np.genfromtxt("c:/kenny/daten/daten1s55.py",dtype = np.str,delimiter=",")
x=data
y11=[]
z=[]
w1=[]
w2=[]
w3=[]
i=0
for i in range(len(x)): 
    if (len(x[i][14]) > 0):
        y11.append((math.acos(math.sin(math.radians(float(x[i][14])))*math.sin(math.radians(54.102427))+math.cos(math.radians(54.102427))*math.cos(math.radians(float(x[i][14])))*math.cos(math.radians(11.735042-float(x[i][15])))))*6378.388)
        z.append(x[i][4])
        w1.append(x[i][14])
        w2.append(x[i][15])
        w3.append(x[i][11])

v=np.column_stack((z,y11,w1,w2,w3))
M = pd.DataFrame(v)
"""M.columns=['Flightcode','Distance','Lat','Long','Height']"""
M[1] = M[1].astype(float)
M1=M.sort([0,1])
M2=M1.reset_index(drop=True)

v1=[]
v2=[] 
v3=[]
v4=[]
v5=[]
ii=0
v1.append(M2[0][0])
v2.append(M2[1][0])
v3.append(M2[2][0])
v4.append(M2[3][0])
v5.append(M2[4][0])
for ii in range(len(z)):
    if M2[0][ii] <> v1[-1]:
        v1.append(M2[0][ii])
        v2.append(M2[1][ii])
        v3.append(M2[2][ii])
        v4.append(M2[3][ii])
        v5.append(M2[4][ii])

Data_gekuertzt1=np.column_stack((v1,v2,v3,v4,v5))  
Data_gekuertzt= pd.DataFrame(Data_gekuertzt1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# alert when airplane closer than 2 or 5 km

q1=0
q2=3

for k in range(len(Data_gekuertzt)):
    if v2[k] <=5 and v2[k]>2:
             q1+=1
    else:
        if v2[k]<=2:
                q2+=1
if q2 > 0:
  winsound.Beep(600,2000) 
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(520, 300))
  w = Label(root, text= 'Airplane within 2 km radius',fg = "red",font = "Helvetica 30 bold italic")
  w.pack()
  root.mainloop()

if q1 >0:
  winsound.Beep(300,2000)  



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#create a logfile


import datetime            
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('loghistory.log')
ch = logging.FileHandler('loghistory.log')
# to empty exisiting file:  logging.FileHandler('loghistory.log', mode ='w')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  - %(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if q2==0 and q1==0:
    logger.debug('No airplanes within 5 km')
else:
    if q2 ==0 and q1>0:
       logger.debug('At least 1 airplane within 5 km') 
    else:
        if q2>0:
            logger.debug('At least 1 airplane within 2 km')
```

Comment: This is just how the FileHandler works. It appends log messages into a file. What would you expect it to do? Or rather.. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @nir0s i eddited my question. What i want to achieve is that the program logs a message every single second or maybe 2 seconds, but only one message, when i run the program several times it adds the same message several times instead of just once.

Answer (score 0):

There is *pattern*: consists of a string that includes the special component that gets replaced at runtime:

> "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts

Please look into the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

Answer (score 0):

You're configuring your logger strangely :)

Remove:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='loghistory.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And it will write a single message to the file. Note that it will, as you stated, overwrite the file before printing every log message, so you will not get a file consisting of multiple entries as the program runs again and again.

Comment: Ok i tried this and it actually helps a little.
Now the file looks like this:

03/07/2017 10:12:00 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 10:12:18 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 10:12:18 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 10:12:18 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km
03/07/2017 10:12:18 AM - loghistory.log - DEBUG - At least 1 airplane within 2 km

So the last entry is still duplicated

Comment: Actually i just noticed it doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Then I might be misunderstanding something. If you expect to have multiple log messages in the log file, this won't do it. You're passing the 'w' flag which means it will just printout a single message everytime. I'm running the code and it recreates the file with a single message in it everytime.

Comment: I know the 'w' deletes all earlier messages, i put that in so i dont have to scroll down every single time i run the code to check whether it still duplicates entries or not.
The problem i have is, that the program currently makes several entries with the same time stamp where it should just create one entry

Comment: I removed the 'w' flag and it writes a single entry no matter which q1 and q2 values I provide. Maybe you have additional code which this imports which defines another logger and so it logs twice?

Comment: i edited the enitre code in the question, although i didnt define another logger, the mistake must be somewhere else

Comment: Again, something is missing. This, obviously, isn't the full code. q1 and q2 are not defined. I'm running this exact code leaving out 'w' and the first dictConfig statement and it prints out a single line for every pair of q1 and q2 values. If you provide EXACTLY what you're doing, I might be able to help.

Comment: q1 and q2 are being defined in the "alert when airplane closer than 2 or 5 km" part of the code.
Have you tried to run the code several times and see what happens with the log?

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
import os
def write_log(filename, log_data):
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    try:
        if not os.path.exists("my_logs"):
            os.makedirs("my_logs")
        with open("my_logs/"+filename, "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write(curr_time + "\t" + log_data + "\n")
    except:
        return
```

I use this function to write logs. This is the easiest approach(as per me) to write logs.

Comment: There's a reason for using the builtin logging module like easy formatting and handling of encoding and single configuration for multiple handlers...